# Cheapest way to mount umbrella softbox reflector for Speedlight?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, lighting-modifiers

I bought 20"*28" Umbrella Softbox Reflector for Speedlight (Model: 6Y19. [Details & dimensions](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Portable-50-70cm-20-28-Umbrella-Softbox-Reflector-for-Speedlight-NEW-6Y19-/131620730987?_trksid=p2047675.m43663.l10137&nordt=true&rt=nc&orig_cvip=true)), assuming I can just mount it on my light stand. That was a mistake. I need this reflector softbox, for portraits and food photography.

---

The problem:

The soft box just came with the box, diffuser fabric and 4 spikes as you can see in the details. So one end of the spikes sticks in a corner of a soft box but the other end has nowhere to stick in. In order to use this reflector softbox, I seem to have 2 options:

1. I purchase Bowen's speedlight ring and Bowen's adapter. But it seems like they'd cost ~$20.00 a piece, costing me extra $40 in total.
2. I could buy [E27 Base socket](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/CY-ceramics-Photography-4-in-1-E27-Base-Socket-Light-Lamp-Bulb-Holder-Adapter-for-Photo/32805605370.html) for less than $20.00 - but then I'd have to be in the proximity of a power outlet.

---

Question:

Is there a solution, which let's me mount my manual flash and the softbox reflector on a light stand, and is also cost effective?

---

EDIT
I have tripod and a light stand with cold shoe mount which I'm using for shoot through umbrellas.

Comment: Are your woodworking skills up to par? Seems like it wouldn't be too big a deal to cut 4 holes into a piece of wood for the box poles and a hole in the bottom to mount onto the tripod...See if Home Depot will give you the scrap for free and cut it to size even. (Or give it to you cheap)...now all you need is to make some holes (get a cheap drill)

Comment: Two words: Duct tape.

Comment: @Hueco I guess that makes sense to me. I'd appreciate if you can please share a template, if possible.

Comment: I can work something up. Can you add a picture of how the poles layout and the length between them?

Comment: Please see if the dimensions at the link below are of any help, the images & details are comprehensive, and I can help with any missing details for sure. There're 4 poles so I think we need the holes to be 90 degree apart, on a circle big enough to hold a flash on light stand: : https://www.ebay.com/itm/Portable-50-70cm-20-28-Umbrella-Softbox-Reflector-for-Speedlight-NEW-6Y19-/131620730987?_trksid=p2047675.m43663.l10137&nordt=true&rt=nc&orig_cvip=true

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the comments indicate that you are asking for help creating or designing a DIY solution. Photography-SE is not a DIY design forum.

Comment: Sorry to see you do that, @scottbb. It was not the original intent of the question.

Comment: I missed the response. Don't forget to @ tag people. scottbb is right, this site isn't a good place for DIY solutions. That being said, this question would be a fit for woodworking (if using wood, obviously). If you ask over there and provide some images and dimensions, I'll submit a template for you. Please @ mention me when you do.

Comment: I do not understand what was actually provided to you and what was not. Can you post a picture of the "almost mounted" stuff?

Comment: @Rafael Please open the "Details & dimensions" link above and then let me know if you've any questions for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. The link of the product is broken, but I am assuming it is simply the softboxes that have an umbrella mechanism inside to open, the flash is inside and the way to hold it is using the umbrella's rod.
2. Do not use the mount you are linking, because it is for continuous light, aka, 4 lightbulbs.
3. Look for a thing called "**E type umbrella holder**"

   The E type is the simplest one where you can change the angle of the system, hold an umbrella and put a flash head on the top using a hot-shoe.

   They are not expensive, about $10 Usd.
4. A safer type of mount is the "**S type umbrella holder**" this holds the Speedlight by the head, not by the hot shoe.
5. Try not to use an improvised solution because your flash can end on the floor.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be to use a gobo-head or a magic arm combined with uni-clamps - the possibilities are endless. I don't know what your sticks are, what kind of contacts and screws you are talking about.

Comment: I don't have a magic arm. It costs more than US $100.00.

Comment: Like I said, the possibilities are virtually endless. Please tell us what you are trying to mount on what specifically.

Comment: Updated my question, to be more clear. Please update your answer accordingly. Thanks!